# How can I gracefully handle denied authorization in AVCaptureDeviceInput.init?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

[The documentation for `AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedeviceinput/1387609-init) documents its parameters as:

> `device`
>   The device from which to capture input.
>
> `outError`
>   If an error occurs during initialization, upon return contains an `NSError` object describing the problem.

This `outError` out-parameter is, in Swift, represented as a thrown `Error`. I can catch and display this like so:

```
do {
    let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
    // ...
}
catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

There is one specific case I want to handle gracefully: when the user has denied authorization for application to use the camera. In this case, I get the following output:

```
Error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11852 "Cannot use FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This app is not authorized to use FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)., AVErrorDeviceKey=<AVCaptureDALDevice: 0x100520a60 [FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)][0x8020000005ac8514]>, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot use FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)}
```

I need to distinguish this error type from other unexpected errors, like so:

```
do {
    let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
    // ...
}
catch AVError.Code.applicationIsNotAuthorizedToUseDevice {
  // Expected error, handle gracefully
  errorMessageBox(errorText: "You have denied authorization to access your camera. Fix this in System Preferences > Security & Privacy.")
}
catch {
  // Unexpected errors
  errorMessageBox("Error: \(error)")
}
```

This is pseudocode and does not compile. I know that the error code `-11852` is [`AVError.Code.applicationIsNotAuthorizedToUseDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/averror/code/applicationisnotauthorizedtousedevice). However, I don't know how to get the error code out of the opaque `error` object in order to test it.

**What is the specific type of the error thrown by `AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device:)`? How do I extract the `AVError.Code` from it in order to handle this specific error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches. One is to check before you even attempt, e.g.

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) == .denied {
    offerToOpenSettings()
    return
}
```

The other approach is to `catch` the not authorized error:

```
let input: AVCaptureDeviceInput
do {
    input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
} catch AVError.applicationIsNotAuthorizedToUseDevice {
    offerToOpenSettings()
    return
} catch {
    print("some other error", error)
    return
}
```

Note, that’s catching `AVError.applicationIsNotAuthorizedToUseDevice`, not `AVError.Code.applicationIsNotAuthorizedToUseDevice`.

If, for example, this was an iOS app, you could have a function to offer to redirect the user to settings app:

```
func offerToOpenSettings() {
    guard
        let settings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settings)
    else { return }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Would you like to open Settings to enable permission to use the camera?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { _ in
        UIApplication.shared.open(settings)
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Note, since this is potentially presenting an alert, you don’t want to trigger this in `viewDidLoad` (which is too early in the process), but rather `viewDidAppear`.

Or, on macOS, maybe something like:

```
func offerToOpenSettings() {
    let preferences = URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Camera")!
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = #"The camera is disabled. Please go to the “Camera” section in Security System Preferences, and enable this app."#
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "System Preferences")
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
    if alert.runModal() == .alertFirstButtonReturn {
        NSWorkspace.shared.open(preferences)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob - unfortunately `AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus` is only available from macOS 10.14 onwards - so I need a workaround for older versions, which is why I was trying to catch the precise error. And `AVError.applicationIsNotAuthorizedToUseDevice` doesn't conform to `Error`, so doesn't compile (I just put this in my question as example pseudocode).

Comment: @jameshfisher - Look at the second example, where I do precisely that, catching the specific error. And, if you notice, I’m just catching `AVError.applicationIsNotAuthorizedToUseDevice` and compiles fine (note, there’s no `Code` in there). But the above is a live example.

Comment: Aha, so sorry @Rob, I lazily misread your answer! You're totally right - `AVError.applicationIsNotAuthorizedToUseDevice` is just the ticket. It works as expected. Thanks so much!